# WordPress: How to change user ID for all users?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need to change user ID for all users in my WordPress web site. I'm planning to change it with query from database because the ID for what I want to change is in the another table. Before I start I wanted to ask how I can perform this properly? Is it enough to change the user ID in wp_users,wp_usermeta,wp_posts? If this is not possible or if this is not a good solution  than any suggestion is welcome :) . One more question, when I register a player with wp_insert_user why I can't define the new users ID? Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: Why does it matter what the ID is?

Comment: If it weren’t important I wouldn’t change it. I imported users from the old page and they must match the ID

Comment: But how are you going to match each use to their correct id? A (tiny) sample data set and desired result would be a really useful way of explaining this problem

Comment: In that another table I store their wp user id, so I can match..